# Computer will not auto sleep

Tags: sleep

I have checked all settings and found out a service is the culprit as below after running command prompt `powercfg -requests`

```
SYSTEM:
[SERVICE] \Device\HarddiskVolume5\Program Files (x86)\Sage\AccountsServiceV26\sg50svc_v26.exe (Sage 50 Accounts Service v26)

AWAYMODE:
None.

EXECUTION:
None.

PERFBOOST:
None.

ACTIVELOCKSCREEN:
None.
```

I have tried using the override command with all option of what to actually put in after `powercfg -reqestoverride` but it is still prevented from sleeping by the service.

I can disable the service and sleep works but then I have to re-enable everytime to use Sage Software.

If I shut the machine down or perform sleep from the start menu it shuts down and sleeps ok. The service runs in the background even with Sage not open but it does not matter if the service is shut down manually.

Comment: Call Sage - their phone support is precisely what you are paying all that money for.

Answer (score 0):

I do pay for Sage telephone support and no matter how hard i try they say it is an it problem and offer no solution or suggestions
The command prompt has now worked but it is unclear at first as to what to put in as all online help skips over the issue
I used powercfg -requestsoverride process sg50svc_v26.exe system
Even though it shows as service it is a process.If you put anymore in it does not work